# How to pause tkinter script until a valid user input is accepted

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a program that has a simple GUI and requires an entry to be a certain length and only be int values. If a valid input is placed such as '12345', I'd like it to be printed to the console. However, if an invalid input was entered I'd like for the script to pause until a valid entry was placed in before continuing with whatever future checks would be implemented.

I thought if I used a while true loop it could do what I wanted it to do, but I'm getting errors with my attempts.

main.py:

```
from tkinter import *
from test import check_entries

def main():
    main_window = Tk()
    app = First(main_window)
    main_window.mainloop()

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('First Window')

        self.entry1 = Entry(self.root)
        self.entry1.pack()

        btn = Button(self.root, text="click", command=self.clicked)
        btn.pack()
    def clicked(self):
        writeDoc(First=self)

class WriteDoc:
    def __init__(self, checklist):
        self.checklist = checklist
        c_num = checklist.entry1.get()

        check_entries(c_num)

if __name__ == '__main__'
    main()
```

test.py

```
def check_entries(x):
    while True:
        try:
            check_cnum = int(input(x))
        except ValueError:
            print('not a valid value')
            continue
        if len(check_cnum) > 5 or len(check_cnum) < 5:
            print('Must be 5 digits exactly')
        else:
            break
```

When I go to test this out, the entry will print out whatever was inputted regardless of size, and hitting the button creates a `RuntimeError: can't re-enter readline`.

Something strange also happens, after I exit tkinter, the inputted value will remain on the terminal (at least on vscode) with each input I put in, and won't let me run the code again until I use Ctrl Z.

Comment: It's not immediately clear if you are trying to create a console application or a tkinter GUI application. The solutions for each are likely to be quite different, and combining the two presents its own challenges. Also, the indentation in your "simplified" example code is incorrect. If you can, it's always best to provide a [mre] that people can actually run.

Comment: @JRiggles Sorry about that, I made edits and made it easier to reproduce. The code is on an offline machine, and I tried to make things easier but it didn't work. The application is a tkinter GUI, however I'm using the console as a debugging method to make sure the code is properly working or not.

Comment: See [ask]. It's unclear. Anyway, it seems you are checking the ```c_num```. Then, do like ```check_cnum = int(x))```. You should not call the ```input()```.